# How do i make Python recognize Shaka Streamer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, shaka

I installed Shaka Streamer according to the instructions from here: https://google.github.io/shaka-streamer/prerequisites.html

But i can't call it from commandline using:
`python3 shaka-streamer`

I get the error:
`python3: can't open file 'shaka-streamer': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I am a bit confused since it is called in that way in the commandline example on: https://google.github.io/shaka-streamer/overview.html

My goal is to call it via commandline in my NodeJS application, i hope someone can tell me where i went wrong and how i can fix it.

Comment: I think that their example is not correct, `python3` command actually expects you to have `shaka-streamer` python file in current directory, but installing `shaka-streamer` with `pip3` actually means you should have `shaka-streamer` command in your `PATH`

Comment: @baldrs You were right, i tried calling it without `python3` but it didn't work. I reinstalled Shaka Streamer completly and called `shaka-streamer` without `python3` and it worked. It seems i did a mistake somewhere and their example is wrong.